# SonataAdminBundle custom rendering of text fields in list

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I'm using symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle.
I have a simple Entity called Post in which I have content field that is basically html text (from a ckeditor for the record). I need to display in the Post list the content field as raw html, without escaping it.
Hacking base_list_field template like this

```
{% block field %}{{ value|raw }}{% endblock %}
```

works, but it's clearly not the proper way.

Comment: You should add your own answer and accept it (after a small delay, I think its two days for self-accept) instead of editing your answer with the solution.

Answer (score 26):

The solution:

I've defined a custom html type in the config.yml for sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
      types:
        list:
          html: MyBundle:Default:list_html.html.twig
```

And created the custom list_html.html.twig template in which i do not escape HTML:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
    {{value|raw}}
{% endblock %}
```

Now in the PostAdmin I can define the behaviour of the field in the configureListFields method:

```
$listMapper
    ->add('content', 'html')
```

Comment: This didn't seam to do anything for me. No error, nothing. Maybe I missed something, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post that has an accepted answer, but now you can also use the **safe** option to tell Symfony not to sanitize the output.

```
$mapper->add('content', null, [
            'safe' => true,
        ]);
```