# Raw filter on Sonata Admin Bundle configureShowFields

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-sonata, admin-generator

I'm doing a project with Symfony2 and Sonata Admin Bundle.
How I can apply the filter raw of twig (to display formated text) in action configureShowFields?

I would not override Sonata templates...

The code of my configureShowFields:

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('active')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('subtitle') // I need this field with twig RAW filter
            ->add('description') //I need this field with twig RAW filter
            ->add('url')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('tags')
            ->add('file');
    }
```

Comment: See the similar question [SonataAdminBundle custom rendering of text fields in list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8729439/2257664) for a simple solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the "safe" sonata field option as follow:

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('subtitle', null, array('safe' => true))
    ;
}
```

It will add the "raw" twig filter to your entity field.

From the base_show_field.html.twig:

```
{% block field %}
    {% if field_description.options.safe %}
       {{ value|raw }}
    {% else %}
       {{ value|nl2br }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: that's the best and easy answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom template.

Under:

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
  templates:
    types:
      list:
        array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
        *** other existing declarations ***
        raw:        MyBundle:CRUD:raw.html.twig
```

Then make the template that the declaration maps to, and give 'raw' as the second argument to add field. It'll then call your new template to render that field.

Comment: I've done:
- Create a folder in app / Resources / SonataAdminBundle / views / CRUD
- Create the file in the folder: base_show_field.html.twig

In this file put:
<th>{% block name %}{{ admin.trans(field_description.label) }}{% endblock %}</th>
<td>{% block field %}{{ value|raw }}{% endblock %}</td>

Comment: Think this means you are now escaping /everything/ - which I'm guessing is what you want. For everyone else - my suggestion above allows you to do it to some fields only.