# Create a custom type field in configureDatagridFilters - Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, filter, sonata-admin

The documentation of sonata admin filter is poor of examples, and they don't show all the options of fields.

So, I need to make or configure a text field and others without the operator select box before, this is too complex for simple users. I trying to develop a search form with a lot of fields without success. I was trying to make a custom template too. I tried what is written in this post [Raw filter on Sonata Admin Bundle configureShowFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597046/raw-filter-on-sonata-admin-bundle-configureshowfields)

Other personalised field that I want is the doctrine_orm_datetime_range but with some default dates filled. I am using the date picker from genemu bundle, like in this post: [Sonata Admin Bundle: DatePicker range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443558/sonata-admin-bundle-datepicker-range)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to hide the operator like this:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ...
        ->add(
            'fieldName',
            null,
            array('operator_type' => 'hidden')
        ),
        ...
    ;
}
```

Cheers,
Marco