# Symfony2 Sonata Admin show attribute only as a readyonly text

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have some immutable attributes on my entity to administrate with sonata-admin bundle.

I want to show them in the edit-view of the entity, but don't want to provide any mechanism to change it (e.g. the value shall not be inside a input field)

I couldn't find anything but this:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('post', 'entity', 
        array(
            'label' => 'Some post', 
            'attr' => array(
                'readonly' => true,
                'disabled' => true
            ),
            'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post'
        )
    )
;
```

I tried it out with `read_only`, `readonly`, `disabled` etc. all the stuff. It looks ok, it's now inside a dropdown (since it is an entity) and I can not modify it.

But I even don't want that. I really need it as text (the current one).

*Especially this is annoying if you use DoctrineExtensions with softdeletable, timestampable, since every "save" saves also the form-data.*

Changing the type to 'text' instead of 'entity' replaces the dropdown with a input-field.. So, what's the best approach here?

Answer (score 22):

```
$formMapper
    ->add('post', 'entity', 
        array(
            'label' => 'Some post',
            'read_only' => true,
            'disabled'  => true,
            'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post'
        )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729439/sonataadminbundle-custom-rendering-of-text-fields-in-list) tells how to customize list rendering. Maybe the same approach works with form rendering?

If not, then you can create your custom form type according to [create custom field type documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html), and customizing the template.

Comment: The customize list rendering looks quite nice, but what about edit mode? I couldn't add a template for editing, and for a new rendering type...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old but this might help someone.

Here is the code that resolves your issue.

```
$formMapper
->add('post', 'entity', array('label' => 'Some post','attr' => array(
                    'readonly' => 'readonly',
                    'disabled' => 'disabled',
                ),
                'class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post')
)
```