# How to fix "The query returned multiple rows" in sonata admin, when groupby in createQuery

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm write a simple code in sonata admin with `createQuery()` for `configureListFields()`.

When I write `groupby` , I get the following error:

> The query returned multiple rows. Change the query or use a different result function like `getScalarResult()`.

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAliases()[0];
    $query->groupby($rootAlias.'.cityId');

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "simple" pager, like explained here due to a bug in the default paginator.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48803077/7135824

In `service.yaml`

```
tags:
    - { name: sonata.admin, pager_type: "simple", ...
```