# SonataAdminBundle List different action depending on object attribute

Tags: list, symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to have different action depending on the object attribute in the List.

My User class has a boolean attribute that I change using a custom action which will have special action such as sending e-mail.

How would I display different action for each object of the list depending on that boolean value ?
Like an editable boolean, but for action Buttons.
Sorry for my english and many thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look a this : [SonataAdminBundle custom rendering of text fields in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729439/sonataadminbundle-custom-rendering-of-text-fields-in-list)

Define a new custom type for the list and use it to display your boolean attribute :

```
$listMapper
    ->add('my_boolean', 'custom_type')
```

And your new type template :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field%}
    {% if value == 1 %}
    <a href="...">Change to 0</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="...">Change to 1</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

If needed, you can access to current object and the admin in your template  :

```
{% set editable = admin.isGranted('EDIT', object) and object.foo == true %}
{% if editable == true %}
    {% if value == 1 %}
    <a href="...">Change to 0</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="...">Change to 1</a>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    {{ value }}
{% endif %}
```

For more information on what you can access in the template, take a look at all the [default list templates of Sonata](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/tree/3.x/Resources/views/CRUD) :